# ASP.Net Application deployment on Windows Server 2003

Tags: asp.net, deployment, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.Net application I developed to a Windows Server 2003 System but I get a error message when running the Site.

The first thing is that I get a Null Reference exception when I want to access my custom configuration section. So I figured that maybe the System.Configuration Assembly might not be installed. However I removed the reference and included the database directly into code to see if it works without.

But now I'm getting another error that a third party server control is not recognized.

> Error Message: Server label
>   "trirand:JQGrid" unknown.

The same application runs just fine on my XP machine with IIS 6 installed so I wonder if I'm missing some installation. This is the first ASP.Net Application on that machine as before there were only ASP tools. I think that the .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 is installed but I'm not sure. Another question is if the ASP.Net is integrated into the .Net Framework of if I need a different install package.

**Update:**

I experienced a weird behaviour: I added the obviously wrong element `<asdf>` to the web.config file. On my development machine that gave me the expected error, but on the server nothing happened at all. So it seems like it some does not recognize my web.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the windows server system is loaded with the software your application required.

The folder `v3.5` should be there in the following location.

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
```

Also you need to check if asp.net is installed on the system, if you are not sure then do install it, installing it if it is already there have no side effects.

To install asp.net type the following commands in DOS prompt.

```
cd C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
// then
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Then also, confirm in IIS that correct version of asp.net is selected for your website.

To check; go to your website properties in IIS
then select `ASP.NET` tab then check `ASP.NET version` it should be `2.0.50727` for websites below .net version 4.0

Good Luck!

Comment: The folder "v3.5" is available. Also the ASP.Net version is 2.0.50727.
Only problem was the aspnet_regsql.exe. For me it seems like this is for registering a sql server to use with asp.net. Did you accidentally choose the wrong exe or is it correct?

Comment: @Towa, Oops it was a mistake; I meant `aspnet_regiis.exe`. Yeah, `aspnet_regsql.exe` is used for some other purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much! The aspnet_regiis.exe worked! I just ran the script and after that everything is working as expected!